# Firebase access child with random generated key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a basic app in which I send messages to the real-time database in Firebase and receive them in a listview.(It's a remake of Whatsapp.) I send the username of the user and the message via a push message to the database. But, I'm not able to read them and create a list view from them because of the randomly generated key. **Is there a way to receive all the children of the reference chat and place them in a listview?**

ps. I can't use the .getKey function because the messages will be coming from different devices.

pps. Extra code or details **can** be provided.

The code:

```
public class MessageBoard extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MessageBoard";

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    private ArrayList<String> chatlist;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private DatabaseReference Users;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_board);

        final Button SignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignOut);
        final Button SendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SendMessage);
        final EditText MessageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Message_Text);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview);
        final TextView UserNameDis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UserNameDisplay);
        if(user != null){
            email = user.getEmail();

        }


        chatlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chatlist);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        ref = database.getReference("chat");

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//to login screen

        if(user == null){
            startActivity(new Intent(MessageBoard.this, Login.class));
            Log.d(TAG, "Login");
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MessageBoard.this, "Login Succesfull.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//to username screen
        if(user.getDisplayName() == null){
            startActivity(new Intent(MessageBoard.this, Username.class));
            Log.d(TAG, "Username");
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MessageBoard.this, "Username Known.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //set username welcome text
        username = user.getDisplayName();
        String Welcome = "Welcome " + username;
        UserNameDis.setText(Welcome);


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//sign out button
        SignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MessageBoard.this,Login.class));

            }
        });



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// chat data update
        ref.orderByKey();

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //where I think the receiving code should be
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//message send
        SendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String push = ref.push().getKey();
                ref.child(push).child("message").setValue(username);
                ref.child(push).child("username").setValue(username);

            }
        });
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve data from the node where u can get every random generated keys and their value.

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
{
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    HashMap<String, Object> allMessage = (HashMap<String, Object>) 
    dataSnapshot.getValue();
    String[] pushIds = allMessage.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    for (int j = 0; j < allMessage.size(); j++)
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> singleMessage = (HashMap) 
        allMessage.get(pushIds[j]);
        Message message = new message(singleMessage);
        allRequests.add(message);

    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
{

}
});
```

Your model class

```
 public class Message
 {
    String message;
    public Message(HashMap<String,Object> singleMessage)
  {
    message = singleMessage.get("message").toString();
  }
  };
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Or a reference to where I can learn more about this?

Comment: it receive all your message data into a Object class. From all objects it takes your all pushid into an string array. then by the help of pushid array it taking one single message which associate with the pushid[j] . But the message is in Hasmap object. so I have to convert it into my object class which is Message. while creating the new object of Message it takes a Hasmap object in constructor and convert hasmap data to my object data ... its little bit confusing. there is other way to do the same but for that  u have to create an extra class .

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any logic on you saying you want to order based on keys which are randomly generated (means, you don't know anything about those keys). Why are you trying to do this? You can use email_id or device_id as the key so that you can track particular node. This saves flowing a lot of internetwork bandwidth because PUSH happens only when particular node changes.

There approaches are better solution in your case:

1) You don't randomly generate key; you can use device_id, which is the unique fixed value as key. So that each client can track specific nodes. -- This is the best way.

2) If you have to have randomly generated key then you can put `Map<ID, MSG_TEXT>` in your JSON message array object (node). But, the problem, here is  every device has to listen on Json Message Array node. If there are millions of device R/W happens, it means, there is unnecessary message can come to your device because based on the datasnapshot definition of firebase, anything inside that JSON message array gets changed, the PUSH happens.

If you have limited number of devices (100 or less) then it is Ok. In this case any device can add value using `setValue("Map<Random_key, msg>")`. Each new message gets new index (like first message has 0, second 1, and so on). So, you can order by index.

What values you can write in Firebase node, see this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Will solution 1 still work when I want everyone who is connected to the database to receive it?

Comment: Yeah, it is, indeed, the standard method. I already implemented this approach in my app. Because you can particularly choose which node you want to listen. And Firebase PUSH server pushes only that message, when there happens change in that node that you did listen. This is the best way, which can scale to billions of devices.

Comment: in that you you generate node based on your device id or email_id then just call setValue("your message")

Comment: I still don't understand how I can put the messages (with device id as key) into a listview. I haven't learned yet how to receive a message without the .child() function. if for example, 2 persons would say to each other the word "hello" there would be keys with 2 different device id's. I don't understand how i can place these into the listview.

Comment: Ok, you generate device id and create Map<device_id, "your string message">. Now you can put whole Map object in your JSON  message array. Firebase automatically does indexing of your each message.